# Supabase Functions - trigger when a file uploaded into Storage bucket

Tags: supabase, supabase-js

I'm looking to create a "pipeline" to manipulate a user's file uploads from a form in my Next.js application.

The files are uploaded into a bucket called `user_uploads`

I want a Supabase function (very originally named `onFileUploadedToUserUploadsBucket()`) to be "triggered" when a new file lands in this bucket (files in this bucket will then be processed and moved into another bucket).

How do I get my function to automatically trigger when files are uploaded into a bucket? I can't seem to find any examples of this behaviour in the GitHub repo.

Comment: You can setup a database webhook for the `storage.objects` table to invoke a function when a new storage object is added to your Supabase storage bucket. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/webhooks

Comment: @dshukertjr thank you. Can these web hooks be managed by code/configuration or do they have to be created manually in each of my environments? This is where firebase seemingly wins as it's all done via code

Comment: Yup, it's just a combination of database trigger and making HTTP request, so you can create it using code. There is a code example on the guide https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/webhooks#creating-a-webhook

Comment: Ah yes, that page looks familiar. Two problems I identify though: 

(1) Lots of overhead. The Webhooks would trigger from the storage `objects` table, but I'd need to check the id of the bucket. Additionally, this function will run _a lot_ as the other buckets will be "busier".


(2) Managing these Webhooks triggers will be difficult across environments as the webhook URL will need to change in each environment. I also can't see an easy way to push out the SQL to create the Webhooks when I deploy my application to each environment.

Comment: (1), just stress test it and see if your Supabase instance has enough computational power to withstand your needs. (2) You can easily push your changes to your Supabase instances using the Supabase CLI. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/cli/getting-started